# How to make a sequence of select, update and insert atomic in one single Cassandra statement?

Tags: cassandra

I'm dealing with 1MLN of Tweets (with a frequency of about 5K at seconds) and I would like to do something similar to this code in Cassandra. Let's say that I'm using a Lambda Architecture.

I know the following code is not working, I just would like to explain my logic through it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hashtag_trend_by_week;
CREATE TABLE hashtag_trend_by_week(
   shard_week timestamp,
   hashtag text ,
   counter counter,
   PRIMARY KEY ( ( shard_week ), hashtag )
) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS topten_hashtag_by_week;
CREATE TABLE topten_hashtag_by_week(
   shard_week timestamp,
   counter bigInt,
   hashtag text ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( ( shard_week ), counter, hashtag )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( counter DESC );


BEGIN BATCH

UPDATE hashtag_trend_by_week SET counter = counter + 22 WHERE shard_week='2021-06-15 12:00:00' and hashtag ='Gino';

INSERT INTO topten_hashtag_trend_by_week( shard_week, hashtag, counter) VALUES ('2021-06-15 12:00:00','Gino', 
SELECT counter FROM hashtag_trend_by_week WHERE shard_week='2021-06-15 12:00:00' AND hashtag='Gino' 
) USING TTL 7200;

APPLY BATCH;
```

Then the final query to satisfy my UI should be something like

```
SELECT hashtag, counter FROM topten_hashtag_by_week WHERE shard_week='2021-06-15 12:00:00' limit 10;
```

Any suggesting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have CQL `counter` columns in a counter table so you need to rethink the schema for the `hashtag_trend_by_week` table.

Batch statements are used for making writes atomic in Cassandra so including a `SELECT` statement does not make sense.

The final query for `topten_hashtag_by_week` looks fine to me. Cheers!